# Can I use streaming structures in ATL?

Tags: atl

Hi
I'm developing a COM component in an ATL project.
I want to use std::ostringstream for logging some trace by log4cxx.
Unfortunately seems that ATL doesn't support std::ostringstream and derivatives.
Does any of you have an idea how can I use streaming classes in an ATL project or any alternative way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I found my mistake. It was a missing header file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "util.h"
#include <comutil.h>

std::ostringstream pvarObject_t2string(VARIANT const *pvarObject)
{

    std::ostringstream str;
    str<<"test";
    str<<"Licence id:   "<< pvarObject[ 0 ].bstrVal;
    return str;

}
```

Comment: Wow. What happens if there's a null BSTR there? What happens if the type of variant is not VT_BSTR?

Comment: yep you are right but they are checked before hand, it's just a code snippet. thx